# Dealing with floating point errors in sums of probabilities

Tags: r, floating-point

I pass three probabilities to the `sample` function in R. One of the probabilities is calculated from the other two (`p3 = 1-p1-p2`), but floating point errors, I assume, mean that the sum is not 1. This sort of error must happen a lot - what is the best way to deal with it?

Minimal example:

```
p1 = 0.9
p2 = 0.1
p3 = 1-p1-p2 #-2.775558e-17

sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), size=10, replace=TRUE, prob=c(p1, p2, p3)) #Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : negative probability
```

Comment: `p3 = max(0,1-p1 - p2)`?

Comment: Hi Monica. See the duplicate link for a detailed discussion of why this doesn't matter.

Comment: @AllanCameron Surely it matters if the computation throws an error.

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, looking at that link it sounds like the probabilities should be normalised - which I hadn't realised. However this doesn't work because the floating point error results in a negative number. John's suggestion will fix this issue though. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnColeman sorry - I meant why the probabilities summing to one doesn't matter. Obviously you can't feed it negative values, and you've shown a good way to prevent that (`p3 = abs(1-p1-p2)`) might be another.